# QGIS import polygons in CSV

Tags: qgis, csv, mac, import

QGIS 1.8 on Mac: I'm hoping to migrate several dozen local maps from my 30 year old Win3.1 plotting system to QGIS. Polygons are in X,Y (CSV), first point repeated at the end to close it, with polygons separated by a blank line. They're each in local coordinates (meters from a corner). I can transform to UTM and replace the polygon delimiter by something else if needed, but it would be easier not to have to.

The format is

```
10,10
20,20
20,30
10,10

5,5
5,6
6,5
5,5
```

I've tried Import as Text Layer: the attribute table shows the values correctly, but each coordinate only shows as a point, the polygon separator lines are omitted, and the layer can't be edited. Tried to export it as vector layer as http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/import_csv.php suggests- export fails. I can't find the mmqgis mentioned in several posts here; the Points2One plugin doesn't do anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By the sounds of it, you will need to format your data a wee bit. Points2One won't do anything because it has no information on how to join the points together by the sounds of it.  It needs an identifier to say which polygon a point belongs to.  Can you show a bit of the data just to be clear on the layout?

Comment: in the following, @ is a new line: X,Y@
10,10@
20,20@
20,30@
10,10@
@
5,5@
5,6@
6,5@
5,5@
@
etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to do some formatting of your data to make them into polygons.  Merely labeling a field as WKT will not help. If you have a lot of files (which it sounds like you do), the most effective way will be to automate your solution by writing a script.

I was going to explain how when I decided that the simplest way would be to write an example script (apologies if I am teaching you to suck eggs!):

```
import os
csvFolder = r"C:\myFolder\mySubFolder"

#----------------------------------------
def writePolyToFile(outFile, polygon, polyId):
    wkt = "POLYGON((" + ','.join(polygon) + "))\n"
    outFile.write(str(polyId) + ';' + wkt)

def makePolys(inPath, outPath):
    try:
        with open(inPath,'r') as inFile:
            contents = inFile.readlines()
            polyId = 0
            polygon = []

            for line in contents:
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                if polyId == 0:

                    if line != 'x,y':
                        print("Unexpected file contents detected in", inPath)
                        break

                    outFile = open(outPath,'w')
                    outFile.write("id;wkt\n")
                    polyId += 1

                elif len(line) == 0:
                    writePolyToFile(outFile, polygon, polyId)
                    polygon = []
                    polyId += 1

                else:
                    polygon.append(line.replace(',',' '))

        writePolyToFile(outFile, polygon, polyId) #append the last polygon after EOF
        outFile.close()
        print('Conversion to WKT OK for', inPath)

    except:
        print('WARNING: conversion to WKT failed for', inPath)

def iterateFiles():
    csvFiles = [each for each in os.listdir(csvFolder) if each.endswith('.csv')]

    for file in csvFiles:
        inPath = os.path.join(csvFolder, file)
        newName = "WKT_" + file
        outPath = os.path.join(csvFolder, newName)
        makePolys(inPath, outPath)
#---------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iterateFiles()
```

This is a very simple Python script which will iterate over a folder of CSV files as a batch process.  It does a crude logic check that the first line of the file follows your format of 'x,y'.  It then collects all the points into an array until it finds a blank line and recasts the array as a WKT string which it writes to an output file of the same name as the original but prefixed by 'WKT_' (so 'firstFile.csv' exports to 'WKT_firstFile.csv' preserving the original file).

Change the following line *csvFolder = r"C:\myFolder\mySubFolder"* to point to a folder containing all the CSV files your want to convert (make sure you keep that 'r' at the start of the path!).

You can now open the resulting files using the normal 'Add vector layer' dialog instead of the 'Add delimited text' dialog.

**EDIT**
Here is a sample of my test:
*Input:*

```
x,y
10,10
20,20
20,30
10,10

5,5
5,6
6,5
5,5

15,15
30,30
30,40
15,15
```

*Output:*

```
id;wkt
1;POLYGON((10 10,20 20,20 30,10 10))
2;POLYGON((5 5,5 6,6 5,5 5))
3;POLYGON((15 15,30 30,30 40,15 15))
```

Comment: Thanks, MappaGnosis, I'll give it a try. I know almost no Python, but should be able to make it work.

Comment: It's my experience that  to render geometries all you need is a csv file with a WKT field containing any valid WKT geometries, and no extraneous rows containing invalid geometries or nulls.  For example, a csv file with a column named "WKT" and a field value of:  "MULTILINESTRING ((10 10, 20 20, 10 40),
(40 40, 30 30, 40 20, 30 10))"  should display a linestring.  The syntax has to be correct.  QGIS 1.8 will ask for the coordinate system.

Comment: @User12711 the OP can't simply rename a field 'WKT' but must recast all the data into WKT before it can be used.  The current format of the data is a simple list of x,y pairs with blank lines to denote a new polygon and no polygon Ids.  This is far from satisfying the requirements of WKT.  So while QGIS can read WKT, it needs some work to reformat the data first.

Comment: @MappaGnosis  Hi, I never specified " the OP can't simply rename a field 'WKT' "  I simply stated WKT field be present and populated with valid entries, and provided a link to wikipedia with the proper syntax for the geometries.

Comment: Before I started working with Python, I tried a manual test, a file containing polygon((.805 10.273,1.535 10.273,1.535 10.363,1.96 10.222)) With add vector file, I get "is not a valid or recognized data source". I can't get delimited text to show anything sensible either. I assume there's some header or similar I'm missing?

Comment: Make sure you have an id column.  It doesn't like it if you don't have one.  Also make sure the first line of your file contains the column headers - I have added an edit to my answer to give you an example. Your example works for me if I save a file as follows: "id;wkt@ 1;polygon((.805 10.273,1.535 10.273,1.535 10.363,1.96 10.222))" (@ is a new line)

Comment: Something's still wrong. I edited my test file as you note, then tried copying your example file above exactly. It still gives "not a valid or recognized data source", for both cases. Might this be one of the Mac/Windows/Linux issues? Or, a 1.8.0 issue?

Comment: I checked codings: "System" is default but saving as UTF-8 & specifying it didn't help.

Comment: @johnsankey You need to have quotes around the geometry because the csv will interpret the commas inside it as indicating each portion in separate columns.  It would think the WKT field is populated only with "polygon((.805 10.273"  with the rest in new columns.  I rendered your polygon nicely using a simple text file.  using this notepad file, exactly as follows, including the quotation marks EXCEPT FOR THE [yourLineFeed]---   PKUID,WKT[yourLineFeed]1,"polygon((.805 10.273,1.535 10.273,1.535 10.363,1.96 10.222))"      --Now load that into QGIS 1.8 and make sure that the name ends with .csv

Comment: Super - it works now. File name .CSV and the quotes did it. Now to expand my meagre knowledge of Python enough to do it for real. Many thanks all.

Comment: Oops - spoken too soon. It loads and shows and says it saves it as ESRI shapefile, but when I load the shapefile the attribute table still shows the WKT format and won't let me select features or edit anything. How do I save it as a standard ESRI shapefile that shows vertices and can be edited?

Comment: Another thing it does, maybe related: when I zoom in, all features that aren't completely contained in the view vanish. Ordinary shape files show partial features on zoom in.

Comment: It works fine for me.  After converting to a shapefile, when you want to edit a feature you must select the layer and then click the little pencil icon to toggle editing.  The vertices then become little red x's.  To move a vertex, click the node tool then click on any vertex (all of that feature's vertices become red squares), then click on the vertex you want to move (becomes a blue square which can be dragged).  Is this what you are doing?

Comment: After converting to a shapefile, it is normal that the WKT field will show as an attribute, but that is all it is and NOT the actual geometry.  You can delete that field if you like as it won't be updated when you edit the geometry of the shapefile.

Comment: I can move points normally, but I can't select any features. That means I can't move one to another layer or delete it. When I add a new feature manually I can select it fine, just none of the ones built by wkt. Editing capabilities say I'm supposed to be able to delete features etc. It seems to be something wierd with select feature.

Comment: It's not just select feature - features added manually to the same layer display normally, it's just wkt-created features that vanish as above.

Comment: I'm struggling to help you because I can't reproduce the issue you are having.  It works perfectly for me.  However, I am running QGIS on Windows.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, MappaGnosis. I've submitted it as a bug, will see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS will load a spatial CSV just fine if it includes a field named "WKT" with the coordinates.  Make sure the geometry follows the proper syntax
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text.

Open your CSV file in a spreadsheet first to make certain there are no rows with Nulls or Blanks in the WKT field, and that every representation is a valid WKT, else delete that row.

simply load that .CSV file into QGIS 1.8 as a file, changing to type from shapefile etc. to CSV format

Comment: WKT is a long way from CSV - it would take an awfully long time to textedit 10k or so polygons to that format.

Comment: WKT (Well Known Text) isn't a file format, it's a format specifying a text based geometry.  It certainly can be included within a CSV file, as a column of geometries in lieu of binary, and loaded into QGIS.  I've done that.

Comment: You are not wrong... but the original data is a long way from being compliant with the specifications for WKT (viz - there is no WKT field), which is why your answer doesn't provide a solution (note the format described by the OP in response to my original question).  My solution is a method of HOW to recast the data into WKT contained within a CSV.  We could write some similar code to create a shapefile, it doesn't matter.  The important thing is to reformat the data to be more "geographic".

Comment: @MappaGnosis  Hi, I had clicked a Thumbs-up on your post to agree with it.  My post simply specified that you use a WKT with valid entries, and then linked to Wikipedia with the definitions for the proper syntax to use in the column to make it valid.  A lot of GIS users aren't aware that a CSV file can be used spatially, and then when they find out they aren't sure of how to implement it.  I hope in the future that users will find that post helpful if they need to know how to create a GIS enabled CSV with geometries, and do a search on stackexchange.